# Apache basic auth with LDAP and reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, http-basic-authentication

So im using Apache 2.4, I want to set up a basic auth connected with LDAP and then, reverse proxy. The idea is to secure a webpage with this authorization. So here is my config:

```
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from All
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Please login"
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   #LDAPVerifyServerCert Off
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap data here
   AuthLDAPBindDN "dn here"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword pass
   AuthLDAPGroupAttribute sAMAccountName
   AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
   #Require ldap-group some settings
   Require ldap-filter ldapsettingshere
   AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 1
   #Require valid-user
   #Satisfy any
   RequestHeader unset Authorization


   ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

ProxyPass / http://numbers:8090/
ProxyPassReverse / http://numbers:8090/
ProxyPreserveHost On
#RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic"
#ProxyRequests           Off
#AllowEncodedSlashes     NoDecode
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

The problem is that when I access my Apache http it doesn't prompt for the basic auth password and login, it just goes straight to the proxied webpage. Any idea what am I doin wrong?

**UPDATE:**
OK, I have uncommented:

```
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic"
```

But now Im in infinite loop of basic auth prompts, which are coming from the end server so its not the case.

Comment: Check the server log files. If the authentication fails apache will keep prompting for credentials.

Comment: I'm sure LDAP itself is fine, I have tested it, there are no LDAP errors.

Comment: OK, this auth prompt was actually coming from the server which I was trying reach. So we can say Im still not getting the prompt from *my* Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this was that I have put the whole Auth part inside `<Directory "/var/www/html"></Directory>`, I have changed it to `<Location "/"></Location>` and it works like a charm!